# C++ std::reduce with array

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, std

```
int arr1[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int sum = reduce(arr1[0], arr1[5]);
```

I wrote this code to use the `std::reduce` function with an integer array. How am I supposed to define the beginning and end of the array?

Comment: Why not use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ? then you will have [begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) and [end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end).

Comment: @TonyTannous I know that it works fine with vectors, just was wondering if it works with arrays too or not

Comment: @TonyTannous C++11 and later have `std::begin()` and `std::end()`, which work for containers and fixed arrays alike.

Comment: `reduce()` accepts iterators, not values of elements.   Options include `reduce(&arr1[0], &arr1[5])`  (note the `&`s),  `reduce(arr1, arr1 + 5)` or (to avoid hard coding the array length, which will break if the array length changes and you forget to update all usages),  `reduce(&arr1[0], &arr1[sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr[0])])`, `reduce(arr1, arr1 + sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr[0]))`.   The preferable approach is to use the standard library, and do `reduce(std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::cbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::cend()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) on the array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
int main(){
    int arr1[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int sum = std::reduce(std::cbegin(arr1), std::cend(arr1));
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GKczse)

Comment: What if the raw array is passed as a parameter to function, will this work?

Comment: @Tony if it's passed as a `T[size]` (which is a specific sized array) and not a `T[]` (which decays to a pointer). See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). Attempting to use `std::begin()` or `std::end()` on a raw pointer will be a compilation error.

Comment: @TonyTannous this depends on the parameter the function u r taking about accepts

Comment: @TonyTannous I tried `int sum = reduce(arr1, arr1);`, it compiles, but returns 0

Comment: @Javadkhan use [reduce(arr1, arr1+5);](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6nf5M)

Comment: Or (and this is a style thing) `std::reduce(&arr1[0], &arr1[5])`. I prefer asmmo's version, but you may see this as well.

Comment: The benefit of using `std::begin(T)` and `std::end(T)` arises when you have an array you're iterating through, but then decide to upgrade it to an STL container. Now you don't have to comb through all of your code and replace your `arr1, arr1 + 5` with `arr1.begin(), arr1.end()`.

Comment: @Tony pointers are iterators, so `std::reduce(ptr, ptr+size)` is valid.

Answer (score 2):

If you often use `<algorithm>` algorithms on containers, you could write something like:

```
template <typename Container>
constexpr typename Container::value_type 
reduce(const Container& container) {
   return std::reduce(std::cbegin(container), std::cend(container));
}
```

Then you can just:

```
int arr1[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
auto sum = reduce(arr1);
```

This has several detriments, including:

- Is only one of the [several variants of `std::reduce()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) - although you could, of course, implement more of them.
- It's in the global namespace (but you can put it within your own namespace, e.g. `util` or `stdx`).
- Doesn't go the "[std-ranges](/questions/tagged/std-ranges) way" (see also [Ranges library (C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)).

---

PS - As @Ben notes, the Boost libraries [have](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.range-algorithms) such container adapters for most `<algorithm>` functions... but not for `std::reduce`.

Comment: BTW, boost provides these functions taking ranges.

Comment: @Ben: You're right, but that [doesn't seem](https://github.com/boostorg/range/blob/develop/include/boost/range/algorithm.hpp) to include an `std::reduce` variant.